# How to set up Linux VPN server and connect from a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to set up my own VPN server on a Linux box which I would connect to from my Mac, and I am having trouble figuring out which is the best and easiest(recommended) way to do that. Which VPN server I should go with? which Mac client I should use?

Answer (score 0):

I have had success in the past with OpenVPN as server and Tunnelblick as client for Mac. A good guide on OpenVPN servers can be found at [TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server/).